Spring Kafka ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate and Reactor Kafka differences for at least once delivery
some questions about Spring Kafka and Reactor Kafka.
Which Spring Kafka properties can be used when using Reactor Kafka through Spring Kafka's ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate . If I configure an ErrorHandlingDeserializer will that be respected ? What about asyncAck will this work or is this intended only for using Spring Kafka through `@KafkaListener ?
Another question in the Reactor Kafka docs there is the statement that receiveAutoAck is not for at least once delivery. But what is the difference to receive and manual ack regarding at least once delivery ? I mean when in both cases reacting to the input stream and then doing some async database operations through flatmapSequential to respect ack ordering (in the case of manual ack) shouldn't the operations produce the same results?

ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate is a wrapper around KafkaReceiver from the reactor-kafka project (https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/snapshot/reference/). The ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate constructor takes ReceiverOptions, which contains Kafka consumer properties. You need to provide these properties when calling the constructor. Currently, neither Spring for Apache Kafka or Spring Boot provides any auto-configuration for these reactive variants. ErrorHandlingDeserializer is meant to be used with the regular message listener container + KafkaListener. When using the reactive consumer, then it is up to the application to provide these types of logic.
In regards to your second question, could you elaborate more? (or start a different thread detailing the use case). In a nutshell, the receiveAutoAck property is for acknowledging records received in a batch automatically by the  framework. It is not clear how the at-least-once delivery guarantee is related here.

But using the Spring Kafka ErrorHandlingDeserializer and defining it in the ReceiverOptions should work right ? About the other question if the frameworks acknowledges the events after the user code has processed them and returned wouldn't that honour at least once semantics? Or does the acknowledging happen before passing the batch of events to the user code?

Yep, you can use ErrorHandlingDeserializer with ReceiverOptions.withValueDeserializer.

Could you ask the questions on ack separately on a different thread?

Yes done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78398663/reactor-kafka-receiveautoack-and-at-least-once-semantics
