Reactor Kafka receiveAutoAck and at least once semantics
In Reactor Kafka when using receiveAutoAck, then if the framework acknowledges the events after the user code has processed them and returned, wouldn't that honour the "at least once" semantics? Or does the acknowledging happen before passing the batch of events to the user code?

Here's how it typically works:

Reactor Kafka consumes a batch of messages from Kafka.
It passes this batch to the user code for processing.
Once the user code has processed the messages without throwing an error, Reactor Kafka automatically acknowledges the messages to Kafka.
If an error occurs during processing, the messages will not be acknowledged, and they will be redelivered to the consumer for processing again.


assume as your thought last one  , if you check the data received to kafka , and when it occurs unexpected error in your user code , now it means current message has no effect and  refer to this mind * acknowledging happen before passing the batch of events to the user code*  kafka would not  repost message ,this message equivalent to deprecated
